# How to make the other Maven project avaliable as normal maven dependency for other during the same pipeline build on Azure Devops?

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, continuous-integration, cicd

I have 2 Maven projects, a Utility project and Main project which is inside a Github repository named My_Cloud_Projects, there projects(utils and cloud) are in 2 different Github Repositories.

I am trying to create a pipeline to first build the utility project then publish
its artifact and download them when building the main project i.e making it avaliable as Maven dependency. But I am getting error the main project can't find utils.

My project structures are are follow:

```
1. Utility
      -> src (where codes is)
      -> pom.xml
2. My_Cloud_Projects structure is as below

      -> main project
            -> src
            -> pom.xml
      -> other maven projects(not important for this question) within this repository
```

Below is how my template looks like, it fails on locating the utils.

````
trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: cloud_projects
      endpoint: mycompany
      type: github
      name: mycompany/cloud_projects
      ref: develop

    - repository: utils
      endpoint: mycompany
      type: github
      name: mycompany/utils
      ref: develop

stages:
- stage: BuildAndPublishUtilsProject
  displayName: Build and Publish Utils Project
  jobs:
  - job: BuildUtils
    displayName: Build Utils Project
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - script: echo "Building the Utils project..."
      displayName: 'Build Step'

    - script: mvn clean package -DskipTests
      workingDirectory: '.'

  
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: './target'
        ArtifactName: 'Utils'

- stage: BuildAndPublishMainProject
  displayName: Build Main Project
  dependsOn: BuildAndPublishUtilsProject
  jobs:
  - job: BuildMain
    displayName: Build Main Project
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - script: echo "Building the main project..."
      displayName: 'Build Step'

    - checkout: cloud_projects
      path: main

    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'Utils'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

    - script: mvn clean package -DskipTests
      displayName: 'Build main Maven project'
      workingDirectory: './main'
    ```

Please help!
````